# How do you I keep information stored next to dynamic list?

Tags: microsoft-excel, links, list

I have a list in my excel sheet that is dynamically changing as it gets updates from another sheet. I want to manually add notes in the columnn next to it, but every time the list gets updated, the notes shift. Is there a way to "link" this notes column to the dynamically changing list so that my notes for a specific cell don't get shuffled?

Thanks!
Katie

Comment: if each row can be uniquely identified, then create another sheet with those unique identifiers and notes, then use a vlookup in the original sheet to pull the note into it.

Comment: Please [edit] your post & share some sample data with us, along with expected output !!